# Taxonomy Checkbox Admin Panel

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have a basic Admin panel allowing Admin to save options using Checkbox.
Checkboxes are used as multiple selection is necessary for the option

So,
Admin Option
- Checkbox 1
- Checkbox 2
- Checkbox 3
etc

My Checkboxes are generated on the fly, successfully with

`<input type="checkbox" name="firm" id="firm-<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>" <?php checked( true, is_object_in_term( $user->ID, 'firm', $term ) ); ?> /><input type="checkbox" name="firm" id="firm-<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>" <?php checked( true, is_object_in_term( $user->ID, 'firm', $term ) ); ?> />`

Then when saving my option, I am trying to do it with

`wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, array( $term ), 'firm', false);`

BUt only the last term is saved and not the array (if more than 1 checked)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the checkboxes from`firm` to `firm[]`.

Then, when you go to save the checkboxes

```
$terms = $_POST['firm'];
```

will give you an array of term slugs that can be checked/sanitized prior to using `wp_set_object_terms` to add the terms...

```
wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, $terms, 'firm', false);
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for your answer. You put me in the right direction, I was checking `$_post['firm']` with `$term = esc_attr( $_POST['firm'] )` which was causing problem. Thanks again

Comment: @Salocin - no problem! Could you except answers that solve your questions - it helps others know it's been solved, and what the solution was :D.